# What's the difference between dart:html vs package:html in dart?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm attempting to create an epub document creator in flutter, and thus need to have something that programmatically builds xhtml files. I'm not sure which library to start with, here, nor what their different purposes are.

Comment: `dart:html` is used for Dart for the web to interact with the browser. `package:html`, as its documentation states, is for parsing HTML without a browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the `dart:html` documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-html/dart-html-library.html):

> HTML elements and other resources for web-based applications that need to interact with the browser and the DOM (Document Object Model).

From the [`package:html`](https://pub.dev/packages/html) package description:

> APIs for parsing and manipulating HTML content outside the browser.

In other words, `dart:html` is used for Dart for the web to interact with a web browser.  `package:html` is an HTML parser without a web browser.